# Microsoft Graph API missing some AD-user properties?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am querying Azure AD with Microsoft Graph API and I need to get AD-properties like "homePhone", "otherPhone" and "description" from users.

I have not seen any explicit mention in the API reference about certain properties being unobtainable, but looking at the user resource type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) there seems to be alot of properties missing.

Am I correct in assuming that these properties can't obtained at the moment?

Comment: Azure AD itself doesn't have those attributes, but you can use extension attributes to extend the schema.

Do you need to get those information over to Azure AD from on-premises AD?

Comment: @JanHajek, Yes, and then I need to query them with Microsoft Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jan hajek said, All Azure AD Directory object properties are not present in Windows AD objects. There is an alternative solution for this is you need to added a custom attribute on the Group schema on the local AD, and then configured it to sync as an extension property to Azure. Please go through this [Directory extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions) document.